# How can I change the perspective of a text in Affinity Designer?

Tags: text, perspective, affinity-designer, ipad, desktop

I know how to draw a text in a circle or semicircle shape but how we can change the perspective? I need it for an project in isometric view.

Regards

Comment: What does "ipad" or "desktop" have to do with your question? Please only add relevant tags.

Comment: @Luciano Affinity Designer for iPad is a redesigned version of an old program. Touch screen support is substatially enhanced, support for Photoshop add-ons is dropped.

Comment: @user287001 but how does that help making the question more clear / specific?

Comment: @Luciano actually the questioner could have written his version to the question. But at least those who know this software do not start with "use this Photoshop plugin"

Comment: I'm actually just trying to help you get better answers to your question, there's no hostility in my comments.

Comment: Thanks @Luciano, me too. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isometric projection doesn't need full perspective tools, you do well with scaling, rotating and shearing. An example:

[image]

Texts stay editable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try this one. That is what I need

Answer (score 1):

Text in Affinity Designer, if still live editable text, can be scaled, mirrored and skewed, but cannot be differentially scaled as you would need to create the illusion of linear perspective in a  drawing.

If you ***were*** looking for *perspective* versus *isometric*, you can convert your text to curves, and once you convert the text to curves, you can manipulate individual anchor knots as  you need to get the effect you want; it will, of course, no longer be live editable text.

You can take an Affinity Designer file and place it or open it in Affinity Photo, which has perspective warp and other warps, and achieve a simple and effective perspective effect that way too.

For classic isometry, as has been noted in a far more on-point answer from User287001, all you need do is skew your text the appropriate direction to get the results you will need - see User287001's excellent answer for details and workflow.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the other answer is what I need. Thanks also for your comment, I will try also your approach. I didn't thought about convert it to curves.

Comment: You should then "accept" User287001's answer if you feel it's the correct one that you will be following!

Comment: Thanks Gerard. I will try it and I accepted after that.